# How to Display or Show FK "Name" or "Title" instead of FK "ID"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, model

I have two tables, one is "Souvenirs" table and another one is "Categories" table. Souvenir from "Souvenirs" table has FK "CategoryID" that is related to "Categoreis" table. The problem is that when I am trying to add a new Sovenir in the drop down field for Sovenir Category the ID of Category is displayed instead of it is title...

Is there a simple solution to change it?
Thanks in advance.

[image: Form Example]

Souvenir.cs

```
using IdentityCore.Models.Product;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IdentityCore.Models
{
    public class Souvenir
    {
        public Souvenir() : base() { }
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Category")]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
        public Category Category { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Category.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IdentityCore.Models
{
    public class Category
    {
        public Category() : base() { }
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public List<Souvenir> Souvenirs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using IdentityCore.Models;
using IdentityCore.Models.Product;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace IdentityCore.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole,string>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Souvenir> Souvenirs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a select list, populated from the "Categories" entity.

In your controller, get the list of categories from the dbcontext, something like:

```
using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    return db.Categories.ToList().Select(d => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Text = d.Title,
        Value = d.Id.ToString()
    });
}
```

Now you have the Categories in a select list, text is the title and value is the ID. So user see the Text, and returns the ID.

In your Model, add a select list property:

```
using System.Web.MVC

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategorySelectList { get; set; }
```

Then in your view, replace the Category list with a DropDownListFor:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryID, Model.CategorySelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I finally looked inside controller properly... and found that string: ViewData["CategoryId"] = new SelectList(_context.Categories, "Id", "Id"); and change it to: ViewData["CategoryId"] = new SelectList(_context.Categories, "Id", "Title");